# toggle class with js, only to selected div

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to toggle visibility on a div by clicking a button in a *neighboring* div. I'm using a class `.expand` to fire the onClick and another class `.target` as the target, but the problem is that every div with the `.target` class fires onClick, instead of just the one I want. Logically, I understand why that's happening, but I don't know how to get around it... Here is a bootply: http://www.bootply.com/oSGM0jOG6q#.

```
$('.expand').on('click', function(e){

    $(".target").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(".target").toggleClass("visible");

});
```

HTML

```
 <!-- Thumbnail -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/400x300&amp;text=Photo1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary expand" role="button">Expand</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Big-Image -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 target hidden">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/1200x900&amp;text=Photo1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>HighRes</h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger expand" role="button">Close</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

PS - I prefer to use bootstrap's hidden/visible classes for clean markup, but am not totally stuck on it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `.closest()` to get the static parent, i just meant static parent as `.thumbnail`, since `col-sm-4`  this class would get change depends upon the layout, i assume. So grab the closest `.thumbnail` and get its parent then target the next sibling to it.

```
$('.expand').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.thumbnail').parent().next('.target').toggleClass("hidden visible");
});
```

### [DEMO](http://www.bootply.com/98d10VYTyb)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find parent div with class `col-sm-4` then use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find `target`

```
$('.expand').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).closest('.col-sm-4').next(".target").toggleClass("hidden visible");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is your bootply http://www.bootply.com/gk8gtlaH1L

Add a div with a new Expand wrapping both the divs. It would be easy for you :)

**JS CODE**

```
$('.newExpand').on('click', function(e){

    $(this).find(".target").toggleClass("hidden");
    $(this).find(".target").toggleClass("visible");

});
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="newExpand">
  <!-- Thumbnail -->
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/400x300&amp;text=Photo1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Thumbnail label</h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary expand" role="button">Expand</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Big-Image -->
  <div class="col-xs-12 target hidden"><!-- use js to add/remove class"hidden" on button click -->
    <div class="thumbnail">
      <img src="//placehold.it/1200x900&amp;text=Photo1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>HighRes</h3>
        <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-danger expand" role="button">Close</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To use a declarative approach that doesn't tie the JavaScript too heavily to the DOM structure, you could set `data-target` on each button element to specify the target element to be toggled when the button is clicked, and update the click handler to find the element(s) identified.

For example:

```
$('.expand').on('click', function(e){
  var sel = $(e.target).data("target");
  if (sel) {
    $(sel).toggleClass("hidden");
    $(sel).toggleClass("visible");
  }
});
```

And in the HTML:

```
<!-- Thumbnail -->
<div class="col-sm-4">
    <a href="#" class="btn expand" data-target="#bigImage" role="button">Expand</a>
</div>

<!-- Big-Image -->
<div id="bigImage" class="hidden">
    This div will be hidden/shown when the button is clicked
</div>
```